# IdentityServer4 certificate change without restart

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, identityserver4, .net-core-2.2

I know that the certificates can be set at startup via

```
AddSigningCredentials(...)
AddValidationKeys(...)
```

But is this also supported/possible while the server is running?

I am thinking about ways to implement automated ways to do certificate key rollovers (under docker) without server restarts.

Like:

- the IdSrv4 app running in a docker container
- the certificates are added from files from a mounted directory (e.g. /app/certs/signing-keys)
- a background process scanning the directory for new files
- once detected a new cert it will be set as validation key
- ...

Answer (score 2):

Internally IdentityServer4 uses an implementation of `ISigningCredentialStore` which by default will be an in memory store that's initialised at startup and then never changes.

There's nothing to stop you from creating your own implementation that pulls this info from anywhere you like (e.g. a memory cache maintained by a background process like you describe).